# How to add all the random generated number that was loop few times

Tags: python

i wanted to add all the ramdom chose item price together into another variable

```
 import random

number_of_thing= random.randrange(0,7)
button = [True,False]
#shopping
shopping = ['shirt', 'dress','hat','jeans','water','hoodie','suit']
price = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]

for i in range(number_of_thing):
    item = random.choice(shopping)
    print(f"{i + 1}. {item}")
    item_tag=shopping.index(item)
    item_price=price[item_tag]
    print(item_price)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and then add expected input and output

Answer (score 1):

```
total_price = 0

for i in range(number_of_thing):
    item = random.choice(shopping)
    print(f"{i + 1}. {item}")
    item_tag=shopping.index(item)
    item_price=price[item_tag]
    total_price += item_price

print(total_price)
```

Comment: @DesmondFoo You're welcome! Does this answer your question?